# Why does this substitution also remove a whitespace character?

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing a script to extract and convert SQL statements from a file. I need to convert the sql unloaded froma gupta sqlbase database into sql that SQLServer can understand.

One task is to replace keywords that are not allowed as column names with a compatible name.

In the following code $commands is an array ref that contains sql statements. (There is actually more code here, but I extracted it because it shouldn't be relevant here)

```
my @KeyWords = ("LEFT", "RIGHT", "PERCENT", "FILE", "PRINT", "CROSS", "PLAN", "TOP", "END", "FILE", "Default", "CHECK", "TEXT");

foreach $cmd (@$commands) {

    foreach my $kw (@KeyWords) {
        $cmd =~ s/\b$kw\b[^(]/_$kw/gi;
    }


    push @$converted, $cmd; 
}
```

This works fine for most statements but in the following command `"DEFAULT"` gets replaced with `"_DEFAULT` instead of `"_DEFAULT"`. So the second quotation mark is lost.

```
  CREATE TABLE SYSADM.SUBTYPE ( ID_SUBTYPE INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  ID_TYPE INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  TYPE VARCHAR(1), 
  BEZEICH VARCHAR(60), 
  NUM_COLOR INTEGER, 
  NUM_TXTCOLOR INTEGER, 
  "DEFAULT" SMALLINT, 
  GENER_ARBA SMALLINT, 
  PROJEKTPLANUNG SMALLINT)
```

Is there a way to modify the regular expression/substition so this will not remove the second quotation mark? Or an other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[^(]` matches any single character that is not a left opening paranthesis.

You want to use a negative zero-width lookahead assertion instead:

```
s/\b$kw\b(?!\()/_$kw/gi;
```

(Alternatively: `(?![(])`)

You can also add the replaced character back to the string:

```
s/\b$kw\b([^(])/_$kw$1/gi;
```

But note that this will not work in all cases. Especially if there is nothing after the keyword, this pattern will not match whereas zero-width assertion will.